# BGLIB SiliconLabs code bug?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, casting

I'm using the SiliconLabs's BGLIB static library for comunicate via SerialPort, with BLED112.
For use this library it's necessary to define two function: one for send and another for receive bytes to and from SerialPort. All data received from serial can be divided in two part: header and data.

Following the "main.c" code of "thermometer-demo" example the function that receive data from serial, receive first of all header and than data. When the header and data has been received, the code parse the header by follow code and initialize a `*msg` variable:

```
unsigned char data[256];
struct ble_header hdr;
int r;

r = uart_rx(sizeof(hdr), (unsigned char *)&hdr, UART_TIMEOUT);
.
.
.
if (hdr.lolen) {
    r = uart_rx(hdr.lolen, data, UART_TIMEOUT);
.
.
.

}

const struct ble_msg *msg = ble_get_msg_hdr(hdr);
```

The `*msg` variable is a `ble_msg` struct pointer and this struct is so defined:

```
struct ble_msg
{
    struct ble_header    hdr;
    uint32               params;
    ble_cmd_handler       handler;
};
```

`handler` is a function pointer that is initialized when `*msg` is inizialized. After parse header the code call this function pointer:

The functions used to initialize this function pointer are defined empty from the library and if you want to use one of this, it's necessary to delete it and rewrite.

In the "thermometer-demo" example is used `void ble_evt_gap_scan_response(const struct ble_msg_gap_scan_response_evt_t *msg)` function to receive all visibled devices and the `ble_msg_gap_scan_response_evt_t` are so defined:

```
PACKSTRUCT(struct ble_msg_gap_scan_response_evt_t
{
    int8    rssi;
    uint8   packet_type;
    bd_addr sender;
    uint8   address_type;
    uint8   bond;
    uint8array  data;
});
```

with `uint8array` so defined:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    uint8 *data;
}uint8array;
```

Here for me there is the problem: when the `msg->handler(data)` code is executed and than the `ble_evt_gap_scan_response` function is called, a cast is executed between data buffer and `ble_msg_gap_scan_response_evt_t` struct and the content of `uint8 *data` (in `uint8array` struct) is initialized with data received from SerialPort and than, will point to a non correct RAM location.

I think the intention is to provide a way to have a directly access to the data but for me is not the correct way.
It's my wrong evaluation or is a bglib bug?

Comment: You cannot cast from `uint8*` to pointer-to-struct and then access the struct. Doing so would be a strict aliasing violation. To solve this, you would either need to rewrite the struct with a wrapper union, or otherwise find a non-standard guarantee that the compiler does not invoke strict aliasing optimizations. This is mostly a concern if the gcc compiler is used - normal embedded systems compilers do not perform the broken (if standard compliant) kind of optimizations that gcc do.

Comment: Ok but this is another problem because in my case the problem is that `*data` point a memory position not valid because initilized with a data received from SerialPort. With your solution this problem persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted SiliconLabs support and that the original libraries are correct and it seem I have a incorrect version of the libraries.

Like the SiliconLabs support suggest me (and like explained very good in this link: http://www.drdobbs.com/questions-answers-creating-variable-siz/184403480), there are 3 possible kind of declarations:

1° declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    uint8 data[0];
}uint8array;
```

and I access to data with:

```
msg->data->data[0]
msg->data->data[1]
msg->data->data[2]
...
msg->data->data[n]
```

In this case could happen compiler warns that the buffer index exceeds the limits.

2° declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    uint8 data[1000];
}uint8array;
```

In this case it's possible to access to data in the same way as previous one but or more space has been allocaded than necessary (in embedded sometime it's important optimize because the resources are limited) or, like previous, you could exceed the buffer limits.

3° declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8 len;
    uint8 data[];
}uint8array;
```

The name of this declaration is **Flexible array member** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and are introduced in the C99 standard. In this case it's possible to access to data in the same way as previouses one but the compiler can warns that isn't a standard declaration.
This declaration is the same adopted by SiliconLabs for the library.

In my case I'm using VisualStudio and I have adopted the third solution but compiler return me the warning C4200 (non standard declaration). I tried the first solution and compiler doesn't return me no warns but for me, the clarity of code is missing and could be a problem for future uses.